# Unable to change UILabel in a method after calling different method in different class

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to update a UILabel with data retrieved from a different class, so in ViewDidLoad, I am calling a method in that different class, then in that class, calling a method in the ViewController to update the UILabel. Here is a simplified version of the code I'm trying to run:

```
import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    test().runTest()
}

func print() {
    label.text = "test123"
}

}
```

and the other class:

```
import UIKit

class test: UIView {

    func runTest() {
        ViewController().print()
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error message printed in the console saying: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"

And an error on the "label.text = "test123" saying: "Thread 1: EXC_Bad_Instruction(code=EXC_(386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you connect the outlet to a label in the storyboard?

Comment: In your `runTest` function you are creating a new instance of your view controller and you are doing so without reference to the storyboard so the label outlet is nil. Either pass the view controller instance to `runTest` when you call it, or, preferably, have `runTest` return the value and have the view controller itself be responsible for updating its label. It is poor design to have one class update another classes views like that

Comment: how are you organizing your view controllers, I might also recommend renaming your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Your label IBOutlet is nil because you are creating a new viewcontroller instance and your viewcontroller is not attached any story board. you can pass self to     func runTest() and on self you can call print. Hope it will help!

You can use this

import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    test().runTest(self)
}

func print() {
    label.text = "test123"
}

}

import UIKit

class test: UIView {

    func runTest(controller:ViewController) {
        controller.print()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are running the function on a new instance of your view controller rather, you should be running it on the already created instance. For instance, if your view is a child of your view controller you can do this, in your class `test` replace edit your function test to be this.

```
func runTest() {
    if let vc = self.parent as? ViewController{
        vc.print()
    }
}
```

This should run the function on the already created instance of your view controller.